# How to update subdocument and delete single object of array in subdocument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is the object that i have:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("590985b1859aefea4a39982f"),
  "comment": [{
    "created_at": 1493880257678.0,
    "comment": "12345",
    "user_id": ObjectId("58edd98d40627c492c8689c5"),
    "_id": ObjectId("590acdc1141b16c6521b9140"),
    "modified": 1493880257678.0,
    "assigned_to": null
  }, {
    "created_at": 1493880257678.0,
    "comment": "12345",
    "user_id": ObjectId("5906c50c1be98711121edf2b"),
    "_id": ObjectId("590acdc1141b16c6521b9140"),
    "modified": 1493880257678.0,
    "assigned_to": null
  }, {
    "created_at": 1493880257678.0,
    "comment": "12345",
    "user_id": ObjectId("58edd98d40627c492c8689c5"),
    "_id": ObjectId("590acdc1141b16c6521b9140"),
    "modified": 1493880257678.0,
    "assigned_to": null
  }]
}
```

I want delete subdocument of comment where `user_id(58edd98d40627c492c8689c5)`

Comment: May you edit the question to be _a little neater_?

Answer (score 1):

you can use findOneAndUpdate with [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/).

you will construct your query like this.

```
findOneAndUpdate(
{_id: <id of the document>}, 
{$pull: {comment: {user_id: <user_id>}}}, 
{multi:true}
)
```

Not sure what client or driver you are using, but here is an example test that I did on robomongo, collection name is "documents"

```
db.getCollection('documents').findOneAndUpdate(
{_id: new ObjectId("590985b1859aefea4a39982f")}, 
{$pull: 
   {comment:{user_id : new ObjectId("58edd98d40627c492c8689c5")}}
}, 
multi:true})
```